# how to parse the json url response of xignite Api using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, api

Iam using xignite Api for displaying silver,gold rates,whenever pass url in json, it does not print any output,plz help me in this regard my code is given below:

```
var dmJSON = "http://globalmetals.xignite.com/xGlobalMetals.json/GetLondonFixing?Symbol=XAU&Currency=USD";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Outcome+ "</td>"+ "<td>" + f.Price + "</td>" + "</tr>";
       $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata");
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont try to iterate in $.each. Try this: 
  Here str is you return data

```
      <html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var str={"Outcome":"RegistrationError","Message":"XigniteGlobalMetals: Maximum number of unregistered requests exceeded. Consider registering or subscribing to expand usage.Your request was authenticated using your IP address 112.196.34.74.  Please visit http://www.xignite.com/registration-help for more information. (globalmetals.xignite.com: 20) ","Identity":"IP","Delay":0.0006475,"Name":null,"Symbol":null,"QuoteType":null,"Currency":null,"Date":null,"Time":null,"Fixing":null,"Price":0.0,"Unit":null,"Source":null};
var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + str.Outcome+ "</td>"+ "<td>" + str.Price + "</td>" + "</tr>";
$('#testTable').append(tblRow);
});
</script>
<table id='testTable'>
<tr>
    <td>Outcome</td>
    <td>Price</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This might help you

Comment: i try the above solution but can not get solution,i tried too much but can not get  solution

Comment: Try my last edit.. Here str is your data return from that API.

Comment: i want to show this through url, my problem is not solve yet plz help

Comment: i want response from this url, as this url print the output, through jquery or javascript http://globalmetals.xignite.com/xGlobalMetals.json/GetLondonFixing?Symbol=XAU&Currency=USD not like above static array.plz help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

In my last answer str is same as data in your question.Its holds the response object return from that URL.

Now try this:

```
var dmJSON = "http://globalmetals.xignite.com/xGlobalMetals.json/GetLondonFixing?Symbol=XAU&Currency=USD";
    $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + data.Outcome+ "</td>"+ "<td>" + data.Price + "</td>" + "</tr>";
        $('#testTable').append(tblRow);
       }
```

Comment: Try this. This will help you for sure :). Let me know it works or not

Comment: but it can not print any thing as well in console also, i used the following url of api help, it print in the console but not on the browser         http://globalmetals.xignite.com/xGlobalMetals.json/GetLondonFixing?Symbol=XAU&Currency=USD&_token=686183D68DA74ED9B45EB62208F579FF?jsoncallback=? how to do print this response

Comment: dear, when i run this url in browser then it works, but if I tried to get data using $.getJSON method then its shows an authentication error. is there any authentication process?